# Filter $lookup results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have 2 collections (with example documents):

**reports**

```
{
    id: "R1",
    type: "xyz",
}
```

**reportfiles**

```
{
    id: "F1",
    reportid: "R1",
    time: ISODate("2016-06-13T14:20:25.812Z")
},
{
    id: "F14",
    reportid: "R1",
    time: ISODate("2016-06-15T09:20:29.809Z")
}
```

As you can see one `report` may have multiple `reportfiles`.

I'd like to perform a query, matching a report `id`, returning the report document as is, plus an additional key storing as subdocument the `reportfile` with the most recent `time` (even better without `reportid`, as it would be redundant), e.g.

```
{
    id: "R1",
    type: "xyz",
    reportfile: {
        id: "F14",
        reportid: "R1",
        time: ISODate("2016-06-15T09:20:29.809Z")
    }
}
```

My problem here is that every report type has its own set of properties, so using `$project` in an aggregation pipeline is not the best way.

So far I got

```
db.reports.aggregate([{
            $match : 'R1'
        }, {
            $lookup : {
                from : 'reportfiles',
                localField : 'id',
                foreignField : 'reportid',
                as : 'reportfile'
            }
        }
    ])
```

returning of course as ´reportfile´ the list of all files with the given `reportid`. How can I efficiently filter that list to get the only element I need?

efficiently -> I tried using `$unwind` as next pipeline step but the resulting document was frighteningly and pointlessly long.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add another [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage to your aggregation pipeline after the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) stage.

```
{ "$project": { 
    "id": "R1",
    "type": "xyz",
    "reportfile": {
        "$let": {
            "vars": { 
                "obj": {   
                    "$arrayElemAt": [
                        { "$filter": { 
                            "input": "$reportfile", 
                            "as": "report", 
                            "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$report.time", { "$max": "$reportfile.time" } ] }
                        }},
                        0
                    ]
                }
            },
            "in": { "id": "$$obj.id", "time": "$$obj.time" }
        }
    }
}}
```

The [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operator "filter" the `$lookup` result and return an array with the document that satisfy your condition. The condition here is [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) which return true when the document has the [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/)imum value.

The [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) operator *slice* the *$filter*'s result and return the element from the array that you then assign to a variable using the [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) operator. From there, you can easily access the field you want in your result with the [*dot notation*](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation).

Answer (score 0):

What you would require is to run the aggregation operation on the `reportfile` collection, do the "join" on the `reports` collection, pipe a **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** operation to ordered (with **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)**) and flattened documents (with **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)**) from the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** pipeline. The preceding result can then be grouped by the `reportid` and output the desired result using the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** accumulator aoperators.

---

The following demonstrates this approach:

```
db.reportfiles.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "reportid": "R1" } },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": 'reports',
            "localField" : 'reportid',
            "foreignField" : 'id',
            "as": 'report'
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$report" },
    { "$sort": { "time": -1 } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$reportid",
            "type": { "$first": "$report.type" },
            "reportfile": {
                "$first": {
                    "id": "$id",
                    "reportid": "$reportid",
                    "time": "$time"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output:**

```
{
    "_id" : "R1",
    "type" : "xyz",
    "reportfile" : {
        "id" : "F14",
        "reportid" : "R1",
        "time" : ISODate("2016-06-15T09:20:29.809Z")
    }
}
```