# mongodb $lookup + regex

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

**Mongo Users**, I have a problem and I would appreciate your help.

I have three mongo collections which behave like in relational database tables:

**contacts_collecion**:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "cid" : "1",
    "email" : "a1@a.aaa"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "cid" : "2",
    "email" : "a2@a.aaa"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "cid" : "3",
    "email" : "a3@a.aaa"
}
```

**groups_collection**:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "gid" : "1",
    "group_name" : "group1"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "gid" : "1",
    "group_name" : "group2"
}
```

**contacts_groups_collection**:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "cid" : "2",
    "gid" : "1"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "cid" : "3",
    "gid" : "1"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "cid" : "3",
    "gid" : "2"
}
```

So I have mamy-to-many relation - every contact can be in every group. **I would like query the mongodb with mongo equivalnet of sql**:

```
SELECT contacts.*
FROM  dbo.contacts INNER JOIN dbo.contacts_groups ON dbo.contacts.cid = dbo.contacts_groups.cid
WHERE dbo.contacts.email LIKE '%a%' AND dbo.contacts_groups.gid = '1'
ORDER BY dbo.contacts.email
```

***1)*** I know how to build a first filter (`WHERE dbo.contacts.email LIKE '%a%'`).

```
db.contacts.find({"email": /a/})
```

With a "C#/.NET Driver Version 2.3" I can do it with (I also need pagination so I have:

```
FilterDefinition<ContactSerial> filter = Builders<ContactSerial>.Filter.Regex("Email", "aaa");
List<ContactSerial> contactsList = m_mongoConn.ContactsColl.Find(filter).Skip(0).Limit(5).ToList();
```

***2)*** I suppose how to achieve an equivalent (not ideal) of INNER JOIN (even though mongo is not relational db). 
I have found a  [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup):
`db.contacts.aggregate([{ $lookup: {from: "contacts_groups", localField: "cid", foreignField: "cid", "as": "details"}}])` 
With "C#/.NET Driver Version 2.3": `mongoConn.ContactsColl.Aggregate().Lookup("contacts_groups", "cid", "cid", "details");`

$lookup will give me

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "cid" : "1",
    "email" : "a1@a.aaa",
    "details" : [ ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "cid" : "2",
    "email" : "a2@a.aaa",
    "details" : [
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
                    "cid" : "2",
                    "gid" : "1"
            }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "cid" : "3",
    "email" : "a3@a.aaa",
    "details" : [
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
                    "cid" : "3",
                    "gid" : "1"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
                    "cid" : "3",
                    "gid" : "2"
            }
    ]
}
```

**My question is:**

***a)*** How to combine a regex filter (1) with a $lookup (2) in a one **MongoShell** query?

 How to do this with a **"C#/.NET Driver Version 2.3"**

***b)*** how to add a second filter (`AND dbo.contacts_groups.group_id = '1'`) in a **MongoShell** query - note this is from the second collection: contacts_gropups not contacts

How in **"C#/.NET Driver Version 2.3"**?

***c)*** how to add to all of this an (`ORDER BY dbo.contacts.email`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) To pre-filter values for your aggregate query, use `match` :

```
db.contacts.aggregate([
  {$match:{email: {"$regex":/a/}}},
  {$lookup: {from: "contacts_groups", localField: "cid", foreignField: "cid", "as": "details"}}])
```

You could also use your predefined filter for aggregation in c# :

```
m_mongoConn.ContactsColl
         .Aggregate()
         .Match(filter)
         .Lookup("contacts_groups", "cid", "cid", "details")
```

2) You need to execute another project after the lookup. See an example here: [Filter $lookup results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37833808/filter-lookup-results)

3) To sort the output in the aggregation pipeline, `Sort` may be used. Note, in your aggregation you get `Contacts` from `Match`, but after `Lookup` you only have Bson. Therefore, it is better to sort between `Match` and `Lookup`

```
m_mongoConn.ContactsColl
         .Aggregate()
         .Match(filter)
         .Sort(Builders<ContactSerial>.Sort.Ascending(c=>c.email))
         .Lookup("contacts_groups", "cid", "cid", "details")
```